# How does this code link two classes to each other?

Tags: django, django-models

this is the code from a django website

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE


class ToDoList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
            return self.text
```

I was just wondering what exactly does

```
 todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

do? It obviously creates a variable called todolist which is simply a model of a foreignkey (as it's not an object defined within Django), but why is there the class "ToDoList" in it? does it take this as an argument or something? I don't quite understand how this links the item class (or the object of that class) to the ToDoList class/object? I hope this is not too confusing

Answer (score 1):

A [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) is a field that refers to a model object. That can be of the same model, or a different model. This thus means that `Item`s can refer to a `ToDoList`.

A `ForeignKey` is a [*many-to-one* relation [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)). This means that each `Item` will refer to *one* `ToDoList`, and a `ToDoList` can have zero, one, or *multiple* `Item`s that relate to that `ToDoList`.

If you load an `Item` into memory, you can load the `ToDoList` it refers to in memory with:

```
myitem.todolist
```

Django will also construct a conceptual relation in reverse. So if you have a `ToDoList`, then you can get all `Item`s that point to that `ToDoList` with:

```
mytodolist.item_set.all()
```

The name `ForeignKey` originates from how you define such field in the database. In the database it will make a field named `todolist_id`, that refers to the primary key of the item it is referring to. You can use the [**`to_field=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) to refer to *another* field, but that field then should be unique.

Most modern databases will add a *foreign key constraint*: it will reject creating or updating objects that have as value a value for which there is no corresponding record in the targetted table.